# How to convert the String date value in to date type value in power bi using DAX formula?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

When we calculate measure in power bi how to convert string date value into date type date value using DAX formula?

"02/04/2020" -> ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have DAX function **`DATEVALUE()`**

```
DATEVALUE("02/04/2020")  -->  02/04/2020

       string data type      date data type
```